# Correct syntax for Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run this code but it's not working when running as a script.

When I run these commands in powershell manually, it works.

Script that does not work:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Enter-PSSession $Computer; Start-Process cmd -Argument "/c C:\Transfer\SETUP2007.EXE /uninstall ProPlus /config UninstallConfig.xml" } -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob
}
```

This works when typed manually:

```
Enter-PSSession pcX
Start-Process cmd -Argument "/c C:\Transfer\SETUP2007.EXE /uninstall ProPlus /config UninstallConfig.xml"
```

I can confirm the  `$computer` returns the correct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it

The solution was to add `-Wait` parameter after the `Start-Process`

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -Wait cmd -Argument "/c C:\Transfer\SETUP2007 /uninstall ProPlus /config UninstallConfig.xml" } -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ener a PS session when running with -computername if you use the same user on both computers. This should work:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Start-Process cmd -Argument "/c C:\Transfer\SETUP2007.EXE /uninstall ProPlus /config UninstallConfig.xml" } -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob
}
```

From `get-help invoke-command -full` :

> To run a series of related commands that share data, use the
>   New-PSSession cmdlet to create a PSSession (a persistent connection)
>   on the remote computer, and then use the Session parameter of
>   Invoke-Command to run the command in the PSSession. To run a command
>   in a disconnected session, use the InDisconnectedSession parameter. To
>   run a command in a background job, use the AsJob parameter.

Example:

```
PS C:\>$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server02 -Credential Domain01\User01
PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't solve the issue as the .exe still doesn't run.